# Difference between JSON web token, bearer token, and MAC token in OAuth2

Tags: authentication, jwt, oauth2, token, mutual

I am reading this [OAuth 2.0 Mutual-TLS Client Authentication and Certificate-Bound Access Tokens](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8705)
where the authorization server issues a client a `JSON web token` with the following format

```
{
"iss": "https://server.example.com",
"sub": "ty.webb@example.com",
"exp": 1493726400,
"nbf": 1493722800,
"cnf":{
"x5t#S256": "bwcK0esc3ACC3DB2Y5_lESsXE8o9ltc05O89jdN-dg2"
}
}
```

However, while I read this [The OAuth 2.0 Authorization Framework](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#page-49) it states that there exist two different types of an access token namely `bearer` and `MAC token.`

So which one can I use? Which are the differences? Which is the format that can I use as a follow the first link? Is the token related to the grand type that is used?

As far as I understand in `oauth2` the `bearer token` is commonly used. Following the guide [Access Token Response](https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/access-tokens/access-token-response/) from here, I see that the access token has the following format

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-store
Pragma: no-cache
 
{
  "access_token":"MTQ0NjJkZmQ5OTM2NDE1ZTZjNGZmZjI3",
  "token_type":"bearer",
  "expires_in":3600,
  "refresh_token":"IwOGYzYTlmM2YxOTQ5MGE3YmNmMDFkNTVk",
  "scope":"create"
}
```

So how `jwt` and `bearer token` are used together? Which is the format used?